# powershell code signing: Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert value

Tags: powershell

Trying to create a self-signed code signing certificate that I can use to sign powershell scripts... Looks like it works except when I try to use the certificate to sign a powershell scriptit gives me the Error "Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert value "

Here's the code that reproduces the problem:

```
# FILE: new_code_signing_cert.ps1
param(
    [switch]$trace
)
try {

    if ($trace) {
       Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
    }

    $base     = "wpmoore_code_signing";
    $password = "password123";
    $outdir   = ".\cert"

    $splat = @{
        Subject           = "CN=Script Automation,E=myemail@gmail.com,O=My Name"
        FriendlyName      = "$base"
        NotAfter          = (Get-Date).AddYears(3)
        CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
        Type              = "CodeSigningCert"
    }

    write-host "Creating Code Signing Certificate...`n"
    $cert   = New-SelfSignedCertificate @splat
    $cthumb = $cert.Thumbprint
    $cpath  = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$cthumb"

    # Backup Certificate with password
    $encrypted = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -Force -AsPlainText

    new-Item -Path $outdir -Type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | out-null

    $pfx_file = "${outdir}\${base}.${cthumb}.pfx"

    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert:$cpath -FilePath:$pfx_file -Password $encrypted | out-null

    write-host "Certificate Location  : $cpath"
    write-host "Certificate Backup    : $pfx_file"

    # Dir of CertStoreLocation
    #Get-ChildItem $cpath

    Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cpath -FilePath .\new_code_signing_cert.ps1
}
finally {
   Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
   write-host ""
}
```

Hwere's what happens when I run...

```
PS> new_code_signing_cert.ps1 

Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert value
"Cert:\CurrentUser\My\C4C3179BAB17C20F33D3D0E23CF88CF500CDBD68" to type
"System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2". Error: "The given path's format is not
supported."
At line:1 char:40
+ ... Certificate Cert:\CurrentUser\My\C4C3179BAB17C20F33D3D0E23CF88CF500CD ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AuthenticodeSignature], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAuthenticodeSig
   natureCommand
```

Comment: Use `$cert` instead of `$cpath` in your `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` command.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Loading certificate using Cert path:

```
$cert2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $cpath -CodeSigningCert
```

Re-Loading certificate from pfx file:

```
$cert2 = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfx_file
```

Once you have the certificate loaded:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert2 -FilePath script.ps1
```

Or use the certificate already loaded:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath script.ps1
```